# pass phpbb login session to another php page

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

Newbie here. I created a custom php page in /myforumroot/script.php if the user isnt logged in it should be saying "not logged in" else it should show the content. any idea why this script isnt working? I just want to link from the phpbb forum to this page so if they're logged in they can access it.

---

script.php is (linked from the forum to this page) ->    domain.com/myforumroot/script.php
forum root dir -> domain.com/myforumroot/

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '/myforumroot';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);

if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
{
echo('NOT LOGGEDIN');
}
else{
include($phpbb_root_path.'config.'.$phpEx);

// test echo
echo $user->data['username'];

?>
```

Comment: This issue has been resolved the problem was a } bracket at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The script looks like it should work for phpBB 3.0, not sure for phpBB 3.1. It would be better to have the link appear only if the user is logged in. This can be done with template variables and a template IF statement.

This tutorial on adding pages might be useful:

https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Adding_pages

The coding guidelines show how to create templating markup to execute logic:

https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/31x/coding-guidelines.html#templating